# Python doesn't see variables in class

Tags: python, arrays, class

```
    class Field:
        __cell_size = 100
        __line_size = 10
        __cells_number = 5
        __lines_number = __cells_number + 1
        __field = [[0 for _ in range(__cells_number)] for _ in range(__cells_number)]
        __next_field = [[0 for _ in range(__cells_number)] for _ in range(__cells_number)]
```

```
NameError: name '_Field__cells_number' is not defined
```

Python doesn't see variable __cells_number when creating array via generator. No need to use function **init**() and no need to create an instance of the class. All class attributes must be private

Try everything, nothing work

Comment: Don't start the class variables with two underscores.  Strange things happen when you do that.

Comment: "when creating array via generator" you are creating a *list* with a *list  comprehension*.

Comment: "All class attributes must be private" **Python doesn't have access modifiers**. All Python attributes in user-defined classes are "public" *always*

Comment: The problem isn't really the double underscores. If your variables didn't have it, it would still fail. The list comprehension doesn't "see" the class variables. The duplicate has an exhaustive explanation and workaround.